# Add properties file when deploying

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am building a web application using IntelliJ 13 Ultimate and a tomcat8 server.
I have a properties file next to my TextUtil class in order to access it with

```
TextUtil.class.getResource(TEXT_PROPERTY_PATH).getFile()
```

But when I am starting my server with IntelliJ, by default the file is not being copied (which is quite logical, because it is not part of the compiler output).

I edited the artifact and added the files manually. But by doing this, the file is not being updated on change without restarting the server.

Is there

A) a better place for the properties-file from where I can access it withou having the context-object or

B) a way to leave the file where it is and get it updated on change?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file in the classpath and use the below code to have the inputstream

For example in ABC.properties or within a folder like properties/ABC.properties

**NOTE:**
After proper build it should go to the path /WEB-INF/classes//ABC.properties

```
public class TextUtil {

....................

//For ABC.properties
 InputStream inStream1 = TextUtil.getClass()
          .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ABC.properties");

//For properties/ABC.properties
InputStream inStream2 = TextUtil.getClass()
          .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("properties/ABC.properties");

 ....................
 }
```